# Jmeter: iterate and increment with every request then go back

Tags: testing, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I have JDBC request that returns a string like: "this is an example". I want to be able to split that string by character (i.e: var_1=t, var_2=h, var_3=i, etc..) and the iterate them in a HTTP Request. Not only iterate, but increment the search pattern every request and then decrease at the end like:

1. request: t
2. request: th
3. request: thi
4. .....
5. request: thi
6. request: th
7. request: t

right now I am using a thread group composed of jdbc request, jsr223 sampler(I've tried with beanshell sampler also but with no success either..), a forEach controller to iterate trough the values, a http request and a response assertion. I haven't been able to make it work because I got stuck at the jsr223 configuration. I guess the right beanshell script would fix this but I suck at groovy script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a BeanShell Sampler after your JDBC request with the below code in the code area:

```
String MyVar = vars.get("MyVar");\\ MyVar is the name of the variable that hold the string returned from your JDBC request.
int x = MyVar.length();

for(i=3;i<=MyVar.length();i++){
    vars.put("Var_" + (i-2), MyVar.substring(0,i));
    vars.put("Var_" + (x * 2 - i -1), MyVar.substring(0,i));

}
```

Then configure your ForEach Controller as below:

- **Input variable prefix:** `Var`
- **Output variable name:** `variable`

Now you can use `${variable}` in your HTTP request which will hold the values you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great. Had some problems initialy with some "Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation" but I fixed it..I know I'm pushing it..but would it be possible to modify it so it starts from the first 3 chars instead of the first one? example: instead of starting with 1 then 2 then 3 etc..to start with 123 then 1234 then 12345 and finishing with 123 again? tnx

Comment: Edited the beanshell to start from the third character

Comment: just found it myself but tnx for all your help!

Comment: It seems I do have some problems..in any of the cases it does not execute the string twice..and it must execute twice..one problem could be the fact that I don't have anything specified in the forEach controller at "End index for loop(inclusive)". I dunno if that is of any importance but the sampler just stops when it reaches full string and does not progress back to have again 3 characters..p.s. would it be possible to put a conditional that the 3rd character should never be whitespace? tnx

Comment: I edited the answer again, please try it and let me know if you have errors, if it works i will check about the whitespace

Comment: Great!Now it works as intended. Any way to slip that "no whitespace in the initial 3 char variable" condition? tnx

Comment: So you want to remove whitespaces from all of the variables? or in case there was a whitespace only in the first 3 characters it should be removed and replaced by the 4th character ? or only remove it without replacing it (making it 2 characters instead of 3) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168229/discussion-between-isus-hristos-and-ararar).